# JQuery $.get or $.ajax call PHP script on server that requires 2 parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created a PHP script  `functionexchangeRate($exchangeFrom, $exchangeTo)` that uses uses two parameters.

I am trying to call this PHP script with Jquery's $.get function but I can not figure out how to send the two parameters (I feel like a turkey - pun intended).

```
var getRate = $.get('exchangeRate.php', function(data){

});
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to use a callback, or call it synchronously:

```
$.get("exchangeRate.php", {exchangeFrom:"what",exchangeTo:"ever"},function(resp){
    alert(resp);
    //resp is what your page returns!
    //find getRate in resp and use it here
});
```

to make things synchronous you need something like

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false,
});
var getRate = null;
$.get("exchangeRate.php", {exchangeFrom:"what",exchangeTo:"ever"},function(resp){
    alert(resp);
    //resp is what your page returns!
    //find getRate in resp
    getRate = something;
});
//use getRate here
```

Also, I guess your PHP is right, with something like

```
 <?php 
   function exchangeRate($exchangeFrom, $exchangeTo){...}
   echo exchangeRate($_GET["exchangeFrom"], $_GET["exchangeTo"]);
 ?>
```

Comment: Gents,

Thanks I will give it a try and get back to you

Bob

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var getRate = $.get('exchangeRate.php', {param1:"val", param2:"val2"}, function(data){
});
```

or

```
var getRate = $.get('exchangeRate.php?param1=val&param2=val2', function(data){
});
```

Comment: I don't think he wants getRate to be the XMLHttpRequest object returned by `$.get`...

Comment: You are right. I guess that is what I get for copying a pasting from the original source. Good catch.

Comment: Trying your suggestions will get back to you hopefully with success

Comment: success! Thanks

I was missing the echo exchangeRate($_GET["exchangeFrom"], $_GET["exchangeTo"]); line in the PHP script.

Thanks again

Bob